# How to detect port changes in real time on Cisco 4506

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst, ssh, cli

Is it possible to detect if any cable was connected/disconnected in real time via Telnet session on Cisco Catalyst 4506?

For example, I have an IBM Switch EN94093R that does it by default, when I unplug and then plug again a cable from the switch, it shows up on the SSH/Telnet session instantly, as shown below:

[image]

Is there a similar way to do this on the Cisco Switch? It is really useful on cases like mine where you don't know the mac or IP addresses.

Comment: Did you turn on "term mon"?

Comment: Do you want to see it on the console, or do you want a snmp trap?  You can also use syslog.

Comment: @RonMaupin I tried to use it, but it wont enable. If I use the command sh logging to check, it shows:
Syslog logging: enabled (0 messages dropped, 150 messages rate-limited, 0 flushes, 0 overruns, xml disabled, filtering disabled)
Console logging: disabled
Monitor logging: disabled

Comment: @Ron I want to see it instantly on the console, specially link up or link down events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From configuration mode, type

```
logging monitor info
end
```

then from enable mode type

```
term[inal] mon[itor]
```

this will send console messages to your vty session.